# How to add a shipping address to Stripe using iOS

Tags: swift, ruby, stripe-payments, payment

I followed the "[Accepting Credit Cards In Your iOS App Using Stripe](https://www.raywenderlich.com/182-accepting-credit-cards-in-your-ios-app-using-stripe)" tutorial for Stripe and iOS and was able to successfully get a payment to go through to the point where I can see the order in the Stripe dashboard.

Now I need to include `shipping address` in the order as well.

In my application "StripeClient.swift":

```
func completeCharge(with token: STPToken, amount: Double, completion: @escaping (Result) -> Void) {
        let url = baseURL.appendingPathComponent("charge")
        let params: [String: Any] = [
            "token": token.tokenId,
            "amount": amount,
            "currency": Constants.defaultCurrency,
            "description": Constants.defaultDescription,
            "shipping": address
        ]
        Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: params)
            .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
            .responseString { response in
                switch response.result {
                case .success:
                    completion(Result.success)
                case .failure(let error):
                    completion(Result.failure(error))
                }
        }
    }
```

My server is: "web.rb":

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'stripe'
require 'json'

Stripe.api_key = ##Secret Key

get '/' do

  status 200
  return "GT Hockey backend has been set up correctly"
end

post '/charge' do

  payload = params
  if request.content_type.include? 'application/json' and params.empty?
    payload = indifferent_params(JSON.parse(request.body.read))
  end

  begin
    charge = Stripe::Charge.create({
      :amount => payload[:amount],
      :currency => payload[:currency],
      :source => payload[:token],
      :description => payload[:description],
      :shipping => payload[:shipping]
  })
  rescue Stripe::StripeError => e
    status 402
    return "Error creating charge: #{e.message}"
  end

  status 200
  return "Charge successfully created"
end
```

I am able to correctly add the shipping address, contained in the `address` variable in application, but I believe something is wrong with the server class and how it creates an order in Stripe.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that **shipping** requires child arguments **address** and **name**. I'd imagine that the charge might not be showing shipping because you are missing **name** argument. For reference on how it's done, look up **Order.create** in the API reference below:

I understand you are creating a charge, but the syntax for including shipping is the same between Order and Charge.

https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/create?lang=ruby